# How to avoid line spacing in label including line breaks

Tags: html, css

We are working on a webapplication with HTML5 and CSS.

On our masks we got labels with single and multiple line texts.

For multiple line we are using the br-tag inside the texts.

Because we are sometimes even using the sub-tag for subscripted charcters inside texts we were forced to use "display:inline" or "display:inline-block" for the label style.

And now we come to the problem: "display: inline" causes line spacings in the labels with multiline texts.

Can these linespacings be avoided by CSS so that all labels - don't matter if they have single or multiline text - have the same look - including the top padding.

Meanwhile we made a try with "display: inline-block".

In case of the multiline label it works fine and the top-padding (in our case 1px) even looks fine.

But in the single line label it causes a much bigger top-padding (by the properties it's 1px like in the other label) which looks like 2 or 3 pixels.

Here a picture of that behaviour with some explanation:

[image]

The goals are:

- Getting the same visual top-padding (1px)
- After using display:inline-block the multiline texts have no unwanted line-spacing anymore but their text lines seem to be glued together. This should not be. It seems to be that adding 1px to the existing line-height could resolve that problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is our actual CSS:

```
// Our pages contains some divs as containers structured like a table.
// Even the controls like the label are in div-containers for vertical alignment of the label content.
.Row{
    display: table; height: calc(100%); width: calc(100%);
}
// CellOuter and CellInner are the classes for the containers in which our controls are.
.CellOuter{
    display: table-cell; padding: 0; position: absolute !important;
}
.CellInner{
    display: table-cell; padding: 0; position: relative !important;  
}
// These style-classes are for horizontal and vertical alignment.
.TopLeft{
    text-align: left; align-items: flex-start; vertical-align: top; 
}
.TopCenter{
    text-align: center; align-items: center; vertical-align: top;   
}
 .TopRight{
    text-align: right; align-items: flex-end; vertical-align: top;  
}
 .MiddleLeft{
    text-align: left;
    align-items: flex-start;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 .MiddleCenter{
    text-align: center; align-items: center; vertical-align: middle;
}
 .MiddleRight{
    text-align: right; align-items: flex-end; vertical-align: middle; 
}
 .BottomLeft{
    text-align: left; align-items: flex-start; vertical-align: bottom;  
}
 .BottomCenter{
    text-align: center; align-items: center; vertical-align: bottom;
}
 .BottomRight{
    text-align: right; align-items: flex-end; vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

And two of our labels.
The first with multiline text and the second with single line text:

```
<div class="CellOuter" style="top: 90px; left: 5px;">
<div class="CellInner TopCenter" style="height: 40px; width: 90px;  border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
<label id="26513" name="RTB_5_6" inilang="false" style="max-width: 90px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; font-weight: bold; display: inline;" textkey="InputField_P150_07_06_RTB_5">Nennformat<br>(cm)</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="CellOuter" style="top: 90px; left: 95px;">
<div class="CellInner TopCenter" style="height: 40px; width: 180px;  border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 0px solid black;">
<label id="26514" name="RTB_6_6" inilang="false" style="max-width: 180px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; font-weight: bold; display: inline;" textkey="InputField_P150_07_06_RTB_6">Abweichung Strahlenfeld (cm)</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you really want to achieve ? I don't understand what are you really trying to get ...

Comment: Yes, a picture please! or something to explain it more clear.

Comment: @elena: We added more explanation. The problem is that "display: inline" causes a line spacing in the multiline label. Meanwhile we made a try with "display: inline-block". Now the multiline label looks good and has a top-padding of 1px as it's defined in our CSS. But the single line label has now a visible padding of 2 or 3 pixels but uses the same style as the other label.

Comment: First of all, you are submitting some css rules in the css which aren't even relevant to the example. This confuses the issue even more. Also, could you just  post some approximate picture of what you expect?

Comment: @elena: Can i add a png to this posting?

Comment: @PatrickPirzer Yes, when you edit the post you will see in the tools the img button.

Comment: @elena: Thanks for Your explanation. I added a screenshot with some explanation to our last use-case with "display:inline-block". It has solved the line-spacing problem but some multiline texts seems to be glued together now and the single line texts have a visually larger top-padding.

Comment: @PatrickPirzer In this example, which I put into jsfiddle, there's no difference in the space between the text and the border: https://jsfiddle.net/lenochka/tvdub6nq/1/ 

Also, I would recommend stick to only classes. Not classes + style for the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for Your support.

After a long struggle we have found a solution for our problem.

By using display:inline-block just the Left and Top of Padding and Margin are effective, but not Top or Bottom.

For that we have to use display:table.

display:table has nearly all functionality of display:inline-box and all defined margins and paddings are effective.